# Serving backup/fail-safe object on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What would be the easiest way to serve backup/fail-safe object when the originally requested object is not available in the bucket?

For example, currently our users can upload custom profile photos which is served from the key e.g. `users/{user-id}/profile.jpg`. Now, when they first sign up they don't have a profile photo so we'd like to display generic profile photo (served on the same bucket) but without the need to write logic on the backend and/or the frontend which would manually display generic profile photo (in case there is none) or the one that is uploaded.

So, in any case profile photo would be served from, let's say `https://cdn.domain.com/images/users/{user-id}/profile.jpg` but the actual served S3 object depends on whether originally requested object exists or not.

Comment: I've never heard of anything like this being possible, but maybe someone else has. I suggest this should be done at the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the S3 bucket for [website hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html) and configure the default image as its [error document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CustomErrorDocSupport.html) (although I admit I have never tried to serve an image directly as an error document but I don’t see why it shouldn’t work).

However note that it’s a global per-bucket setting so it will return that default image for all invalid URLs in the bucket.

Hope that helps :)